# npm install in a specific local folder

Tags: node.js, npm-install

I'm currently trying to execute the command `npm install` to get all dependencies and modules necessary to run my package.json.

The problem is that I don't have Internet access to fetch from the internet, so I have downloaded the `node_modules` on a different PC and copy-paste it on my local folder that contains all. If I tried to run `npm install` without arguments, it's still trying to fetch from internet and fails.

I have read their documentation and apparently they have listed few `npm install` that takes different arguments, but still, I'm unable to install from the folder already downloaded.

I've tried to do `npm install node_modules` on the path that contains the `package.json`, but nothing. I'm running on windows 7.

If someone has an approach to specifying the local `node_modules` and just install all modules inside, I'll appreciate.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably should use [npm-link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link)...
From the docs:

Go to the `node_modules` directory, and, inside each package, run `npm-link`:

```
$ cd node_modules

$ cd package-name
$ npm link
$ cd ..
...
```

In the directory of your project which needs the local modules:

```
$ npm link package-name
```

Comment: So I have to go to each package and link all package-name.js inside every module?

Comment: You have to cd into every package directory and run `npm link`. A shell script to automate it should be trivial...